# Properties of the Integral (rudin theorem 6.12 a)

Tags: real-analysis, integration

if $ f_1 \in \Re (\alpha) $ and $f_2 \in \Re (\alpha)$ on $[a,b]$ , then $f_1 + f_2 \in \Re (\alpha)$ .

proof:

if $f = f_1 + f_2$ and $P$ is any partition of $[a,b]$ we have:  $L(P,f_1,\alpha) + L(P,f_2,\alpha) \leq L(P,f,\alpha) \leq  U(P,f,\alpha) \leq U(P,f_1,\alpha) + U(P,f_2,\alpha)$

can someone pls explain how to arrive to the first and last inequality. the first one is :

$L(P,f_1,\alpha) + L(P,f_2,\alpha) \leq L(P,f,\alpha)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I take it you're assuming $\alpha$ is increasing on $[a,b]$. Then $\Delta \alpha_i>0$. Now, for any $x$ in a subinterval $S_i$ of a partition of $[a,b]$ we have $f(x)\leqslant \sup_{S_i}  f$ and $g(x)\leqslant \sup_{S_i}  g$. This means that $f(x)+g(x)\leqslant \sup_{S_i} f+\sup_{S_i}g$. Taking the supremum on $S_i$, we get $\sup_{S_i} (f+g)\leqslant \sup_{S_i}  f+\sup_{S_i}  g$. Can you move on with the infimum and conclude by multiplying by $\Delta \alpha_i >0$ and summing throughout all subintervals ${S_i} $ of the partition?